Protecting Routes using React Router DOM v5
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import { ChakraProvider } from "@chakra-ui/react";
import {BrowserRouter} from "react-router-dom"
import ChatProvider from "./Context/ChatProvider";

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <ChatProvider>
      <ChakraProvider>
        <App />
      </ChakraProvider>
    
    </ChatProvider>
  </BrowserRouter>
    
  
);


import './App.css';
import HomePage from "./Pages/HomePage";
import ChatPage from "./Pages/ChatPage";
import TrialPage from "./Pages/TrialPage";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import ProtectedRoute from "./utils/ProtectedRoute"
import ProtectedRouteTwo from "./utils/ProtectedRoute"
import { ChatState } from './Context/ChatProvider';
import { useEffect } from 'react';

function App() {
  
  const {user} = ChatState()

  useEffect(()=>{
    console.log("userDSE",user)
  })
  
  return (
    <div className="App">
    
      <Route path="/" component={HomePage} exact />
      <Route path="/chats" component={ChatPage}exact/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;

Does anyone have any idea how to protect my routes for "/chats", I configured my routers this way while following along a YouTube tutorial. I have been trying to look for solutions
online but they were mostly for v6

You can put your component inside <Switch> and use render to conditionally render your component with <Redirect>
<Switch>
  <Route path="/" component={HomePage} exact />
  <Route 
    path="/chats" 
    exact
    render={(props) => 
      user ? (
        <ChatPage {...props} />
      ) : (
        <Redirect to="/" />
      )
    } 
  />
</Switch>


That works for me! However just a slight issue is that while it re-routes correctly, it momentarily(0.5s) displays the page of the protected route

@brown_dorito I think in this case you might want to change your ChatProvider. I'm not sure how it's been implemented, but generally you can add a loading state const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true), and in the place where you fetch the user information (usually inside useEffect), add setLoading(false) after fetch data is completed. Then you pass this loading state into the value, after this you can access loading state with const { user, loading } = ChatState() in your App component and add an if(loading) check before the return code
